# Does the change of the eventType specification in the Calendar API v3 affect CalendarApp of GoogleAppsScript?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

On February 8, 2024, I received the following email from "Google Developers.
"[Action Required] Update your applications to include notification improvements for Google Calendar API v3"

If I do not specify any value of the eventType parameter when retrieving event.list with Calendar API v3, the returned value will be changed from March 11, 2024.

*If no value is specified for eventType
Currently:
Events with ["default", "focusTime", "outOfOffice"] are returned.
After March 11, 2024:
Events of "workingLocation" will be returned
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list?hl=ja

Will this API change affect the use of CalendarApp service of GoogleAppsScript?
Currently, there is no method to specify eventType when using getEvents of CalendarApp.

I guess that the CalendarApp service also works by calling the calendar API behind the scenes, so we would like to know if this change will affect this service.
After March 31, 2024, will the method of "getEvents" of CalendarApp of GoogleAppsScript work the same as it does now?

Comment: I asked about it to Google. I got a response from Google as follows. They say that this is only applied to Calendar API, and it is not applied to Calendar Service (CalendarApp). So, about your question of `After March 31, 2024, will the method of "getEvents" of CalendarApp of GoogleAppsScript work the same as it does now?`, it's yes. If this information is useful, I'm glad.

Comment: Tanaike-san,  
Thank you for your reply and sorry for replying late as I received the notification email today regarding your comment.  
I also have received an answer from Google Workspace Support and it says as below.  
"本アップデートが CalendarApp サービスにも影響があることが確認できました。getEventsForDay(date) などに関して追加で Working Location events が返ってくるとのことでございます。そのため現在の動作に大きな影響なく動くことが予想されます。"
※こちらから日本語で失礼します。
私は当初「eventTypeを指定しないと、これまでとは違って Working Location Events のみが返ってくるようになる」と勘違いしていました。ですが実際は「これまでの返り値に ”追加で” Working Location Events が返されるようになる」というGoogleからの回答でした。

Comment: Thank you for replying. It seems that your comment is different from the situation I directly have with the developers at Google. I'm worried that the specification might be changed after it. But, I'd be glad your issue was resolved. If your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

#### Received an answer from Google Workspace Support

I have received an answer from Google Workspace Support. It says as below.

- The change of the eventType specification in the Calendar API v3 affects the CalendarApp of GoogleAppsScript.
- After March 11, 2024, the methods like getEvents() of the CalendarApp in GAS, will return "Working location events" in addition to the current values.
- i.e. CalendarApp will return ["default", "focusTime", "outOfOffice", "workingLocation"] events After March 11, 2024.
- This behavior also works in the Calendar API v3.
- i.e. If we do not specify any value of the eventType parameter when retrieving event.list with Calendar API v3, it will return ["default", "focusTime", "outOfOffice", "workingLocation"] events After March 11, 2024.

As mentioned by Tanaike-san in the comment, I'm worried that there's a bit difference between the 2 answers from Google.
But I think it won't be any BIG impact as the "working location events" will be just added to the current response of the API.